# Why awk does not remove BOM from the middle of a line?

Tags: awk, unicode, grep, byte-order-mark

I try to use awk to remove all byte order marks from a file (I have many of them):

```
awk '{sub(/\xEF\xBB\xBF/,"")}{print}' f1.txt > f2.txt
```

It seems to remove all the BOMs that are in the beginning of the line but those in the middle are not removed. I can verify that by:

```
grep -U $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' f2.txt
```

Grep returns me one line where BOM is in the middle.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is that there are more than one BOM in one record and `sub` only removes the first one. Easy to verify with `gsub`.

Comment: gsub really resolves the problem However, I still do not understand why. Doesn't sub replace every occurrence of a specified sub-string by another specified sub-string?

Comment: No, it only replaces the first occurrence in each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned `sub()` will only swap out the leftmost substring, so if global is what you're after then using `gsub()`, or even better `gensub()` is the way to go.

***sub(regexp, replacement [, target])***

> Search target, which is treated as a string, for the leftmost, longest
> substring matched by the regular expression regexp. Modify the entire
> string by replacing the matched text with replacement. The modified
> string becomes the new value of target. Return the number of
> substitutions made (zero or one).

***gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])***

> Search target for all of the longest, leftmost, nonoverlapping
> matching substrings it can find and replace them with replacement. The
> ‘g’ in `gsub()` stands for “global,” which means replace everywhere.

***gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target]) #***

> Search the target string target for matches of the regular expression
> regexp. If how is a string beginning with ‘g’ or ‘G’ (short for
> “global”), then replace all matches of regexp with replacement.
> Otherwise, "how" is treated as a number indicating which match of regexp
> to replace. `gensub()` is a general substitution function. Its purpose is to provide more features than the standard `sub()` and `gsub()` functions.

There's tons more helpful information and examples linked below:

↳ [The GNU Awk User's Guide: String Functions / 9.1.3 String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)